# Error while building the demonstration environment for Stucco on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, ansible

On following the instructions in http://stucco.github.io/

I am getting the following traceback on terminal:

> TASK [smola.java : Install Java packages]  **************************************
>
> failed: [stucco] (item=[u'java_packages']) => {"failed": true, "item":
>   ["java_packages"], "msg": "No package matching 'java_packages' is
>   available"}
>
> Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
>   visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.

Any idea on how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/stucco/dev-setup/tree/master/provisioning) playbooks are two years old. They use abandoned Ansible syntax. For example [here](https://github.com/stucco/dev-setup/blob/master/provisioning/roles/smola.java/tasks/Debian.yml#L22:L24):

```
- name: Install Java packages
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=latest
  with_items: java_packages
```

You can't use bare variables in `with_` with modern Ansible versions (latest version to support this with giant deprecation warning was 2.1).

From Stucco Dev-Setup [manual](https://github.com/stucco/dev-setup/blob/master/README.md):

> Download Ansible. (Tested with version 1.7.x.). (Ansible requires Python 2.6.)

Comment: Thanks, using ansible version 1.7 fixed that issue :)